# better way to write the for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I want to loop through the array and check the condition using 'if' statement. If the condition is met then it should exit the for loop and execute other statements. after executing other statements, it should loop from next variable. 
for ex. if I have a array named 'songs',

```
_(songs).forEach(function(song) {
    if (song.genre == 1){
       //do something and exit from for loop 
    }
});
// Do something else
```

Now I want to again loop through and start from where it left off earlier. I tried to achieve this like below:

```
var i = 0;
for(;i < songs.length; i++){
            if(songs[i].genre == 3) {
                //do something
                i++;
                break;
            }
            else if(songs[i].genre == 2) {
                //do something
                i++;
                break;
            }else{
                //do something
                i++;
                break;
            }
        }
```

It serves the purpose. but is there anyway to make it efficient or better? Any suggestion would be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function doStuffWithSongs(song) {
  switch (song.genre) {
    case 'pop':
      // handle pop songs
      break;

    case 'rock':
      // repeat for every genre
      break;

  }
};

songs.forEach(doStuffWithSongs);
```

You could also have `doStuffWithSongs` be a bunch of different functions and handle the `switch` in the `forEach`:

```
songs.forEach(song => {
  switch (song.genre) {
    case 'pop': return handlePopSongs(song);
    case 'rock': return handleRockSongs(song);
    // etc.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have some objects to hold functions and songs

```js
var songs = [{
    "genre": "pop",
    "name": "Hit me baby"
  }, {
    "genre": "rock",
    "name": "Smoke on the water"
  }],
  handlers = {
    pop: function(song) {
      console.log("pop", song.name);
    },
    rock: function(song) {
      console.log("rock", song.name);
    }
  }
for (var i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
  handlers[songs[i].genre](songs[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless for some reason your needing to keep order? You really should run a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the songs array creating a "genre" array, you could then simply loop through each array executing whichever function or actions you needed to take place.

```
//SONGS ARRAY
var songs = [
    {
        'name':'Work',
        'genre': 0
    },
    {
        name: 'Blessings',
        genre: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'Blame',
        genre: 0
    },
    {
        name: 'She Got It',
        genre: 0
    },
    {
        name: 'Controlla',
        genre: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'Get Low',
        genre: 1
    }
];

//FILTERED GENRE ARRAYS 
var myRockSongs = songs.filter((o)=>(o.genre === 0) ? true : false);
var myPopSongs = songs.filter((o)=>(o.genre === 1) ? true : false);

//CONSOLE LOG
console.log(myRockSongs);
console.log(myPopSongs);
```